# Assigning cell value based to vlookup result - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

After failing to figure out how to do that for a while, I'll try my luck here:

I'm essentially trying to compare two situations using VBA.
A similar (and a lot simpler) example:

[image]

F2, for example, calculate 152+D2, while F3 calculates 185+D3.

I wish to run a macro that would check the effect of one person getting a different amount of points. For example, if A2 = Max the macro should assign the value of A3 (18) to D3. If A2 = Lewis, 18 would become the new value of D2.

Tried using vlookup and match+index in order to find the cell that I want to change. When using vlookup, the code looked similar to this:

First I copied F2:F4 to I2:I4, so the results would be comparable. Then tried to replace the value of D2:D4 according to A2&A3:

```
name = Range("A2").value
newvalue = Range("A3").value

Find = Application.VLookup(name, Range("C2:D4"), 2, False)
Find.value = newvalue
```

Perhaps I should be looking for the cell itself, and not the value, and then it would work (maybe using offset, or offset+match? couldn't make it work)?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: `Range.Find` is probably the easiest solution for Columns C and D. I don't understand what you are trying to do with Column F, where do the original numbers come from and why does it need to be copied over to Column I?

Comment: Column F is not really relevant. Perhaps I didn't explain it clearly. Ignore F - I want to assign the value in A3 to D2/D3/D4, based on the while matching the name in A2 to C2:C4. So if A2 = Max, A3 = 18, the value of D3 should be replaced (using macro) from 0 to 18. A2 and A3 are dynamic and these are the cells I might change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the intention is but this seems like a fun challenge.

So logic is this. We look for the name in column C. If we get a match we will get a row back as an answer, then we replace the value from "A3" and add it to the row we got but to the column D.

Maybe something like this :D?

```
Option Explicit

Sub something_test()
 
Dim lookup_val As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lookup_rng As Range
Dim match_row As Long


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name the worksheet

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1

lookup_val = ws.Cells(2, "A").Value 'Set the lookup value
Set lookup_rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & lrow) 'set the lookup range


match_row = Application.Match(lookup_val, lookup_rng, 0) + 1 'Find the name in column C. Add +1 since the range starts at row 2. We will get the row number back
ws.Cells(match_row, "D").Value = ws.Cells(3, "A").Value 'Take the value from "A3" and replace the existing value at the row we found, but for column D
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, much appreciated :)

Comment: Your're welcome, happy to help :D. I should mention the drawback with the match function is this: If you have two cells with the name "Max", it will always find the **first** one in the column. If this is a problem then you need to have another column which separate the name "Max" or we can loop through the range. Let me know if you need some help and I can update the answer :). Good luck with your project :)!!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Assuming it isn't sensitive ("Maxin" would be counted as "Max"), which doesn't seem to be the case, it should work fine). And managed to transform it to my actual project where it also worked (with minor adjustments). Thanks again for the detailed and intelligible answer! Have a lovely day :))

Comment: No it's not. You need a wildcard for that to occur i.e. "Max*". Lovely! You too =)!